# Get child page data from master page selectedItems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have location DropdownList in my master page. I have set control in my child page which takes properties from master page. Now I am running a query

```
SELECT * FROM table where city like '"+city.text+"'
```

here city.text gets value from master page selected cities. But my problem is it's not actually showing records as per city.text has values in it. It shows any random records.

My Code

Master Page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="locationSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected>Pune</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Delhi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Chennai</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bangalore</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Mumbai</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Child page VB Code

```
Dim location As DropDownList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
        city.Text = location.SelectedItem.ToString

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Try
                query = "SELECT * FROM hospitals where city like '" + city.Text + "'"
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim table As New DataTable
                da.Fill(table)
                ViewState("Data") = table
                hospitals.DataSource = table
                hospitals.DataBind()

            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        End If
```

UPDATE

```
Protected Sub hospitals_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        Dim location As DropDownList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
        city.Text = location.SelectedItem.ToString
    End Sub
```

Sometimes it also throws TimeOut error. But most of the time It gets results but not as per selected items. What will be any other solution for this?

Comment: what type of control is "hospitals" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use prerender event within page. In prerender event try to access your master page control and get value.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tips:

1) Timeout errors can happen for a number of reasons, including lots of other traffic to the site, connection pools all used up etc. I would, for a small list of cities, maybe keep that in a cache after the first call, so that you do not need to load the city list from database every time. Depending on your country, if you only have a few thousand cities, then just put it in an in-memory list.

2) You are using a "SELECT *" which is usually not really cool to other developers, nor to your code if the table contains more than just a city name. IF you write **Select CityName from Table**, then you will effectively have reduced the amount of data going from your database to your program, and it is clear to the other developers exactly what you're pulling from that table.

3) If you have an ID for the city, it will likely perform even better as string matcing is REALLY slow compared to matching a couple of ID's. I've seen 20% speed improvements by replacing strings with constants, you wouldn't believe how slow strings are in code these days.

4) Last, and I think you may already have done this, make sure that you INDEX every field that you do a WHERE filter on. If you search for Hospitals, then make sure that the Hospitals.City field is indexed to avoid row lookups.

I hope (any) of this helps you :)

Comment: you mean I should create cookies of cities. And once city selected first time & then get cities value from cookies?

Comment: No. Think of it as a singleton in your code - the first time you load up the cities, you check first "Do I have my cities object != null?) and then fill it up, server-side with cities from the database. Additional requests can then do the same check and deliver cities from your in-memory thing :)

Comment: I would suggest to use prerender event within page. In prerender event try to access your master page control and get value.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri On Pre_Render Event I tried this but it's not working. See my updated code as u said I added. please check

Comment: do you get city value in pre render event?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need to change below

to fetch the selected TEXT value use `location.SelectedItem.Text` instead of `location.SelectedItem.ToString()`

```
     city.Text = location.SelectedItem.Text // change here
```

before binding the dropdown control check the no. of rows

```
if(table.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                hospitals.DataSource = table;
                hospitals.DataBind();
            }
```